# How to get the "pong" response on "ping" call using Python websockets library?

Tags: python, websocket, ping

I have an application that subscribes to a web-socket and, from time to time, receives from it some information. In some cases it might happen that my application does not receive anything for a relatively long time. In that case I might suspect that web-socket have "died". However, it might also be the case that web-socket just does not have anything to send and I just need to wait longer.

So, in such situations I do not want to guess what was the reason for the delay. I just want "actively" ask the web-socket if it is still alive. I have learned that one can do it with "ping" but I am not sure how exactly it works.

For example I can do the follwing:

```
pong_waiter = await ws.ping()
```

But what I should do with this object? I guess I need to see a "pong" string when the web-socket is alive, but where can I see it? What does return this string?

**ADDED**

If I execute:

```
pong_waiter = await ws.ping()
await pong_waiter
```

I did not get anything. After that I also execute:

```
pong_waiter.result()
```

It also returns nothing. But I know what web-socket is alive (I am still getting information from it).

ADDED 2

If I execute:

```
pong_waiter
```

I get:

```
<Future finished result=None>
```

So, where is "pong"?

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you're asking. There's no literal pong being sent. A pong message is just a control frame with an opcode of `0xA`, optionally followed by a payload.

Comment: The fact that your `pong_waiter` `Future` completes successfully indicates that you have received a pong control frame in response to your ping control frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `await` it if you want to wait for the `pong`:

```
pong_waiter = await ws.ping()
await pong_waiter
```

If you expect the `pong` to contain a custom payload, you can most likely get it from the `pong_waiter` `Future` by calling `result()` after it completes.

Comment: I have executed the two lines of the code that you have proposed. After that I have executed "pong_waiter.result()". This did not return anything.

Comment: Well, it's just a standard [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future). You can interrogate it using that API. I assume that if `result()` doesn't return anything, the `pong` didn't contain a payload.